# How to store value of a tensor in a tf.while_loop()

Tags: python, dictionary, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a recurrent neural network designed by hand with a [tf.while_loop()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop). I want to store all values of some outputs during the training, to see how it is working. But I want to do so for every kind of features.

Which mean I have to match the corresponding input to it's hidden state during training. In order to do so I declared a global `Dic = {}` and use it in the body of the loop:

```
def body(t1, t2, h, x_array, l_middle):
    global Dic
    x = x_array.read(t1)
    if x.eval() in Dic:
        Dic[str(x.eval())] += 1
    else:
        Dic[str(x.eval())] = 1
    h = tf.multiply(h, x)
    print(type(h))
    h.set_shape([1, 24])
    l_middle = tf.concat([l_middle, h], axis=0)
    t1 = tf.add(t1, 1)
    return [t1, t2, h, x_array, l_middle]

def iterr2(L, ll, N):
    x_array = TensorArr.unstack(x)
    L = tf.unstack(ll)
    h = tf.ones([1, n_hiddens]) * 0.01
    for i in range(11):
        l_middle = tf.zeros([1, 24])
        aux = L[i]
        right = L[i + 1]
        s = L[i].get_shape()
        T, _, g, _, l = tf.while_loop(
            cond,
            body,
            [aux, right, h, x_array, l_middle],
            shape_invariants=[
                s,
                s,
                h.get_shape(),
                tf.TensorShape([]),
                tf.TensorShape([None, 24])])
    return T, g, l
```

This is not working since `ValueError: Operation u'while/TensorArrayReadV3' has been marked as not fetchable.`

If I don't eval() it then I just have 10 of those gentlemen in my Dictionary : `Tensor("while_2/TensorArrayReadV3:0", dtype=float32)`

If you need the full log of error or some code to make it run I can provide it but I thought it would make a too long question.

Comment: Please read @skye's answer to the git [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13616)

Comment: In fact i think i can handle this problem outside the loop and after having called the sess.run() so that I will only use numpy objects